# Strange Catch Try Finally Error

Tags: android

I've got a strange error with the android LiveWallpaper catch try finally. When I set this
It works on API's around 2.3ish:

```
    Canvas canvas = null;
    //Keep trying till wallpaper is set.
    //Error around here..
    try 
    {
        canvas = this._surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
        synchronized (this._surfaceHolder) 
        {
            this.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    } 

    finally
    {
        if(canvas != null)
        {
            this._surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
```

And this works on ICS & Honeycomb (tested on real devices)

```
    Canvas canvas = null;
    //Keep trying till wallpaper is set.
    //Error around here..
    try 
    {
        canvas = this._surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
        synchronized (this._surfaceHolder) 
        {
            this.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    } 

    finally
    {
        if(canvas != null)
        {
            this._surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
```

The error occurs when the livewallpaper is "Set". (The service fails, "exception locking service")
How would I get it to work on both from one compile? I don't want two different versions.

Comment: There isn't really a question here. What's the error you're having? And, because I'm either blind or going crazy, what's the difference between those two code snippets - they look identical to me?

Comment: What @weston says, plus - if you are using try and finally, shouldn't you be catching something too? Your app is crashing because you aren't catching the exception that is being thrown.

Comment: if you find useful plz  tell me

Comment: Yeah the code is the same, I accidently pasted over the other code sorry! It's working now with the Try Catch Finally, thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of try catch is :

```
try {
    // Code
} catch (<the Exception type to catch> ex) {
    // Exception handling code
} finally {
    // Code for after
}
```

NB: The program will only catch the exceptions that you specify. If you don't cover all exceptions possible, it won't be handled. See [catch blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) from the Java tutorials by Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

syntax of try catch is 
try{

}catch{Exception e)
//code to catch exception 
}finally{

}

write code exactly as per Java convention